# Consider x and y positive integers. Which is the smallest positive integer value that $|11x^5−7y^3|$ could assume?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, diophantine-equations, integers

Consider x and y positive integers. Which is the smallest positive integer value that $|11x^5−7y^3|$ could assume?

I tried to separate in two cases. First, with $11x^5\geq 7y^3$. Clearly, the smallest value is 4. The second case $7y^3>11x^5$. I did some euclidean divisions, but I couldn't get anywhere.

Comment: It is easy to get 0, eg $x=11\cdot7^2,y=11^27^3$, but getting to 1,2 or 3 looks hard (and hard to disprove).

Comment: For $y^3>x^5$ and $1\le x, y\le 10^4$, the smallest difference I get is $437$ at $x=1$, $y=4$. That seems high, so there may be an error in my computation.

Comment: Shouldn't the cases be $11 x^5 > 7 y^3$ and $11 x^5 < 7 y^3$?

Comment: You should get difference $16$ for $x=5, y=17$.

Comment: Observe that you can parametrize all solutions of $ 11a-7b=1$ as follows  $$a'=2-7t\qquad \quad b'=3-11t$$ since $(2, 3)$ is a solution. The solutions of $11a-7b=n\in\mathbb N$ are therefore $$a'=2n-7tn\qquad \quad b'=3n-11tn$$

Comment: If you could completely solve the case $x^5>y^3$ , please show the proof. Perhaps it can be modified to solve the other case as well.

Comment: @Dr.Mathva I think you mean $a' = 2n -  7 s$, $b' = 3n - 11 s$.  There's no reason for $s$ to be divisible by $n$.

Comment: It's a multiple choice exercise. The possible alternatives for choosing are 1, 2, 3, 4, or none of the answers. But I don't know if it's correct.

Comment: Why is it clear that the smallest value is $4$ in the first case?

Comment: Because taking $x=y=1$, the difference will result in 4. If we take any other value that $x>y$, the first number will be obviously much more greater than the second, because 11>7, resulting in difference greater than 4.

Comment: @Dunck and why must $x>y$? There's absolutely no reason to believe that to be the case!

Comment: @Dunck This is essentially a problem dealing with the algebraic surface $11x^5 - 7y^3 - z = 0$, asking for the integral points of said surface. This is a very hard problem, as solving for the integral points of elliptic curves are already hard enough.

Comment: This problem could be simplified down to asking about the integral points of the algebraic curves $7y^3 = 11x^5 + 1$, $7y^3 = 11x^5 + 2$, and $7y^3 = 11x^5 + 3$.